# How to get a response from a website several seconds after the connection using python?

Tags: python

I want to search flight information on a website, and when I provide DepartureAirport and ArrivalAirport, the website would give a response after several seconds(typically 5-10 seconds). I know how to use `my_web = urllib2.urlopen(my_url)` to connect to a website, but how could I get a response after several seconds instead of getting a immediate response after connection?

ps: The website I mentioned above is(in Chinese):

http://flight.qunar.com/site/oneway_list_inter.htm?searchDepartureAirport=%E7%A6%8F%E5%B7%9E&searchArrivalAirport=%E8%8A%9D%E5%8A%A0%E5%93%A5&searchDepartureTime=2014-08-03&searchArrivalTime=2014-04-02&nextNDays=0&startSearch=true&from=qunarindex

When I used `urllib2.urlopen()` to open it, the information about flight appears piece by piece. And what I want to do is to get all pieces of information when they are completed loaded.

Comment: How does this website "give a response after several seconds"? Does it use Ajax?

Comment: So are you wanting to delay receiving the response or just wait before doing something with it..?

Comment: Can you kindly post some code so we understand exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @LutzHorn I added some additional information about my problem. I do not know whether or not it uses Ajax.

Comment: @Drewness I added some additional information about my problem :)

Comment: @BK201 I do not have codes now, and I added some additional information about my problem :)

Comment: It sounds like he's saying that the service takes several seconds to load -- is that correct?  If so, it sounds like you want to make the URL connection asynchronous, and come back to it when it's finished.

Answer (score 1):

`urlopen()` returns a file-like object. Simply calling `readlines()` should block and read everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some sort of asynchronous I/O library. Take a look at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) or [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/).